# The toolbar of the database window in phpstorm is missing

Tags: database, phpstorm, toolbar

My database and the toolbar disappeared from the Database Window. It seems that i cant enable it by clicking on the "settings"-icon and clicking "Show Toolbar" because i dont get the options.

I allready tried reinstalling the plugin and restarting the computer. Nothing worked for me.

Has anybody noticed a similar problem and could solve it?

I would appreciate any help.

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PULc4.png -> i would assume there should be a toolbar instead of nothing

Comment: Any screenshots .. or should we just guess what you have got there?

Comment: Its back, so an answer is no longer needed. I also dont know why it went away and why it is back

Answer (score 4):

**Install the PHPStorm plugins 'database Tools and SQL'**

If you click on MENU > VIEW > TOOL BUTTONS you must view appear a 'Database' icon around the PHPStorm window.

Otherwise you can map directly the function view with the keyboard shortcut.
Enter into Settings > Keymap and search database. It sort in 'Other' category. Fix the shortcut with any key on your keyboard.
Now use this new keyboard shortcut attribute and test if you can view the window Database.

If you don't have create a database connection, perhaps create this.

Answer (score 2):

[please check for database toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uxBQ.jpg)

[how to get database window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss7Gf.png)

i m using phpstrome 8.0.1 i have made changes in my phpstrome editor as shown in image this will help you please refer the image

please check the second image there is setting button you click on that button and you will get show toolbar option

Comment: I get the Database Window, but i dont get the Toolbar inside the Database Window.

Comment: I cant click on "show toolbar" because it is not there to click on

Comment: which phpstrom version you are using

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, for me solution was re-activating the database plug-in , which was disabled by mistake.

Go to Settings, Plug-ins, search for "database", a plug-in named "Database Tools and SQL" should appear and be selected.

Check if the checkbox near the plug-in name is checked, if not, check it. 
That's it.

Restart PhpStorm and the Database Window will be there.

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtSvQ.png)

1. click: File > Settings > Plugins . A window will open as shown in the image above.
2. Search for: Database Tools and SQL (if not found click on install jetBrains plugin..search for Database Tools and SQl and first install it)
3. Enable and Apply
4. Restart

Answer (score 0):

In left down corner is pic with two squares on it, try to click it. This button switch some view modes in php storm.